# Validate Boolean True of an Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a model **Assignment** which **belongs_to** model **Device**

before an Assignment row gets created I need to validate that a boolean value for the corresponding device is set to true otherwise the creation should fail. How can this be done?

Comment: could you try my answer? It should work. If not, let me know. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rails custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) to validate your `Assignment` model based on it's Device's `boolean_attribute`.

In your `Assignment` Model, add this custom validator:

```
validate :true_device_attribute
```

Then, define the validator method in the same Model:

```
 def true_device_attribute
    unless device.boolean_attribute
      errors.add(:boolean_attribute, "Device's boolean_attribute Must be True")
    end
 end
```

By default, such validations will run every time you call `valid?`.

You can also control when to run your custom validator. If you only want to perform the validation while `creating` the `assignment`, then you can pass `:on :create` option to the `validate` method like this:

```
validate :true_device_attribute, on: :create
```

Then the validation will only run when you try to `create` `Assignment` records. Not for `update`.
By default, it will work for both `create` and `update`.

Look at the [Rails Official Documentation for Validations Custom Methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) for more insights.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Assignment < ...

validate :check_device_boolean_value

def check_device_boolean_value
  errors.add(:your_boolean_value, "must to boolean") unless devise.your_boolean_value
end
```